# How do you get your application to deploy after the datasource has been bound in JBoss 4.2?

Tags: jboss, datasource, managed-bean

I have a JBoss 4.2 AppServer running, with a mysql-ds.xml defined. I also have a set of custom jars that I want deployed as an mbean, which use the bounded MySQL connection as java:/MySqlDS.

However, it seems the jars get loaded before the datasource is bounded.

Is there a way to ensure an MBean is loaded after the datasource is bounded?

Here are the log entries:

```
11:39:29,639 FATAL [DatasourceConnectionProvider] Could not find datasource: java:/MySqlDS
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MySqlDS not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
...
11:39:29,666 ERROR [HibernateUtil] Building SessionFactory failed.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MySqlDS not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:296)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
    ... 106 more
```

Then later on:

```
11:39:30,524 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MySqlDS' to JNDI name 'java:/MySqlDS'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i just had to add a depends statement in my MBean declaration:

```
<depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MySqlDS</depends>
```